# How to create a Html table using DOM model using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, dom, html-table

How to create a Html table using DOM model using Javascript?

for ex:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="tblMCNRoles">   
</table>
```

I have above table and i want to render above table like below by using DOM modal creation.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="tblMCNRoles">

<tr>
 <td bordercolor="green" align="center" valign="top" style="border-style:dotted" >
   <table width="99%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" 
      class="portlet-table-body intable5"> 
      <tr><td align="center" valign="middle" class="grid6"></td></tr>
   </table>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the DOM Table methods since neither appendChild nor innerHTML are good for safe cross browser manipulation.

The DOM has insertRow and insertCell which works better.

Here is [IE's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  and here is an example from [Mozillas Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Examples#section_8)

```
<table id="table0">
 <tr>
  <td>Row 0 Cell 0</td>
  <td>Row 0 Cell 1</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

var table = document.getElementById('table0');
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var cell, text;
for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
  cell = row.insertCell(-1);
  text = 'Row ' + row.rowIndex + ' Cell ' + i;
  cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
}

</script>
```

Comment: There's a short [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Examples#Example_8:_Using_the_DOM_Table_Interface) on the MDC site.

Comment: @RobG That is the same link I have posted and the code from there too

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = document.getElementById("tblMCNRoles");
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td = document.createElement("td");
//set attributes via setAttribute()
//add subtable via createElement and appendCHild
tr.appendChild(td);
table.appendChild(tr);
```

Or you can use innerHTML, but then you have to generate the HTML first